# r calling dataframe variable by column number

Tags: r, regression

New to R, how do you perform a regression in R without listing the variable name, but instead the column number?  I have many regression I want to estimate on a loop, I'm trying to do this,

```
stepreg<-with(newdata, lm(OutputChg~Furrow))
```

And I want to call `Furrow` by its column # instead of title.  Is this possible?  As always, any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Depends on what you are actually doing? See `lm.fit` and create the model matrix you want for a given variable before passing it to `lm.fit`. Usual warning to not do this if you are going to dredge through your data; if you are planning on doing that I assume you understand the issues. Depending on how many columns/models you want to fit, you could do this with the leaps pkg already. Also, don't use `with()` with modelling funs with a formula. Use the `data` argument instead as that's what it is there for: `stepreg <- lm(OutputChg~Furrow, data = newdata)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could construct a formula inside each loop and use it in the regression, something along the lines of

```
allnames <- names(iris)[-5] # find names to which you wish to regress

for (name in allnames) {
  myformula <- formula(sprintf("%s ~ Species", name))
  print(summary(lm(myformula, data = iris)))
}
```